# Firebase - ForEach Loop Counting

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a code like this:

```
    firebase.database().ref(...).on('value'.function(snapshot) {

        snapshot.forEach(function(minisnapshot) {

            var counter = 0;
            alert("test");
            //
            minisnapshot.child("books").foreach(function(mainsnapshot) {

                counter +=0.5;

                    var data = {
                       price:mainsnapshot.child("price").val() * counter;
                       ...
                   }

                }

           }

        }
```

The format looks like this. The problem is that for each loop for the books the counter is being set to 0 again. It is executing `var counter = 0`, hence counter is always 0.5 (*I want it to be 0.5,1,1.5.. and so on*).

How can I implement this kind of a counter that is only specific to the `books` ForEach?

Comment: Are you sure that the snapshot is an array?

Comment: @Sandrooco it's a [Firebase DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot). While that is not an array, it *does* have a `forEach()` method.

Comment: Isn't the snapshot whatever you tell it to be in your database? (list with unique keys or normal object)

Comment: foreach works but the problem is it is executing counter = 0 for each one loop. I do not know why

Answer (score 0):

Here problem is that you are initializing counter variable inside the forEach loop, You just need to take it outside the loop. Your code will be:

```
firebase.database().ref(...).on('value'.function(snapshot) {
      var counter = 0;
      snapshot.forEach(function(minisnapshot) {
            alert("test");
            //
            minisnapshot.child("books").foreach(function(mainsnapshot) {
                  counter +=0.5;
                  var data = {
                        price:mainsnapshot.child("price").val() * counter;
                        ...
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes, But forEach minisnapshot I want to set the counter back to 0.